# Properties of Integrals and Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Let $f:[1,3] \to [4,15]$ denote a bounded integrable function and $G(x) = \int_{1}^{2+x}{f(t)} \cdot dt$ for all $x \in [0,1]$.

$(i)$ Use the properties of integrals to prove that $4x \leq G(x) - G(0) \leq 15x$ for all $x \in [0,1]$. ($3$ marks)

$(ii)$ Use part $(i)$ to prove that $lim_{x \to 0^+}G(x)=G(0)$ ($2$ marks)

$(iv)$ Use the First Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to find a real number $c$ such that if $f$ is continuous at $x=c$, then $G$ is differentiable at $x=0$ with $G'(0)=f(c)$. ($1$ mark)

I am confident on $(i)$ but not the rest. Here is my working. Can the $3$ parts be checked please ? I am mainly struggling on the final part.

$(i)$ Using the extension properties of the integral, we can write $G(x) - G(0) = \int_{1}^{2+x}{f(t)} \cdot dt - \int_{1}^{2}{f(t)} \cdot dt = \int_{1}^{2}{f(t)} \cdot dt + \int_{2}^{2+x}{f(t)} \cdot dt - \int_{1}^{2}{f(t)} \cdot dt = \int_{2}^{2+x}{f(t)} \cdot dt$

Now using the estimation property of the integral, noting that $G$ is bounded below by $4$ and bounded above by $15$, we have: $4((2+x)-2) \leq G(x) - G(0) \leq 15((2+x)-2)$ $=$ $4x \leq G(x) - G(0) \leq 15x$ as required. $\square$

$(ii)$ Apply the limit  $lim_{x \to 0^+}$ on the inequality in $(i)$: $lim_{x \to 0^+}(4x) \leq lim_{x \to 0^+}(G(x) - G(0)) \leq lim_{x \to 0^+}(15x)$. This can be rewritten as $lim_{x \to 0^+}(4x) \leq lim_{x \to 0^+}(G(x)) - G(0)\leq lim_{x \to 0^+}(15x)$ because $G(0)$ is not a function of $x$ using algebra of limits sum / linear rule . By the algebra of limits product rule and using the fact $lim_{x \to 0^+}(x)=0$, we have $0 \leq lim_{x \to 0^+}(G(x)) - G(0) \leq 0$. So $lim_{x \to 0^+}(G(x)) = G(0)$ as required. $\square$

$(iv)$ I wrote down the First Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. I know it is too simple for $c$ to be $0$ but I am unsure on what else it could be for $1$ mark too. I know $G(0) = \int_{1}^{2}{f(t)} \cdot dt$. And then by the First Fundamental Theorem of Calculus we should have $G'(0) = f(0)$, which means that $f$ must be continuous at $x=0$.

Am I supposed to combine the First Fundamental Theorem of Calculus with the Chain Rule ?

Comment: Part (iii) follows from (i) by the squeezing principle. Part (iv) is strange. If $f$ is continuous at $c,$ then $G(x)$ is differentiable at $c-2$ and $G'(c-2)=f(c).$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I did use the sandwich theorem but forgot to say in my answer. Is my logic correct for $(iii)$ though ? What does that mean the value of $c$ is then ?

Comment: Yes (ii) is fine. I do not get (iv). The existence of $G'(0)$ requires right hand side continuity of $f$ at $2,$ at least to my knowledge. Fortunately it costs just $1$ mark. Perhaps you can afford it.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc It's just revision I am doing, no worries. The feedback says: "most students were unable to combine the FTC with the
Chain Rule in such context."

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc so you are saying you think $c=2$?

Comment: Exactly $c=2,$ if you need $G'(0).$